# React native is not connecting to socket.io

Tags: react-native, sockets, websocket

I'm building news app.
I created reusable component for my news in which I am displaying them one by one.
I'm trying to connect to the socket.io server by id of the current article but it is not working.

Here is how I'm trying to achieve it.

```
 useEffect(() => {
const socket = socketIoClient(URL, {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  jsonp: false,
});
socket.connect();
socket.on(`connect${currentPost.id}`, () => {
  console.log('connected to socket server');
});
}, [currentPost.id]);
```

URL is link of heroku

It is connecting to the server  if I only write 'connect' without currentPost.id and I don't understand why.

I'm using react native version:0.63.3
And socket.io-client": "^2.1.1"

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it set up right now is that on every `currentPost` change you try to connect the socket again, although the connection should already be established.

Moreover, you are waiting for an event on the socket which I'm afraid does not really exist (although that depends on how serverside socket communicates with your frontend). It works for just plain `socket.on('connect'...)` because it's what socket [understands](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99).

If you make clearer what exactly you want to achieve, I may try to provide additional help, for now I'm not sure about your final goal and how you diverge from it.